# Hyperledger Composer 0.15 & Web applications - Use of cards

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I developped my blockchain with composer 0.14 without problem. I managed my users (participant) with secrets and everythings was stored in the blockchain.

Now with Composer 0.15, we have to use cards to connect to the blockchain (even if a hidden function exists). I want to respect the current philosophy...

If I well understood, now I have to manage users in my webapp and make a relation between my users and theirs cards for connection to the blockchain to the right particpant. Am I right?

And other question, how to deal with multiple webapp using same particpants, do I have to generate cards on each servers?

Finally, how to make access more secure for cards saved on a server? Because, user cards can be used without theirs assent (hacking, bug, ...)

Web server : Ubuntu/NodeJS - the question can be asked for all plateforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > *now I have to manage users in my webapp and make a relation between my users and theirs cards for connection to the blockchain to the right particpant. Am I right?*

its more accurate to say - map your identity to the right participant in Composer.

> > *multiple webapp*

if you're spinning up separate web apps, they can use the same business network and the identities they authenticate with are mapped to participants in Composer. If an identity (mapped to a participant) uses one of those webapps then it can (say) transact on the business network in question. You could for example set up a persistent shared store accessible by your webapps or deploy a REST server with a persistent store for cards -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

> > secure storage of cards

Hardware Security Module (cryptographic hardware-based option for key storage)? Trusted Platform Module ?